# TikZ: How to place pictures / shapes at a child-node in a tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

Is it possible to place pictures at a child-node in a tree, say at "`Y`"? 
For example a rectangle *or even a more complex figure from several shapes* (in the original I need to draw a 'steelyard').

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,]
\node {A0}
child { node {A1} 
        child{ node{X}   }
        child{ node{Y}   }
        };

\draw[thick, fill=yellow] (0,0) rectangle (2,1) node[midway]{Figure};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shall figure show a photo, a tikz-graphic or similar?

Comment: In place of `Y` you can do `\includegraphics{picture-of-steelyard}`. Or you could draw something at that point (perhaps by creating a phantom `Y` placeholder).

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean? You can always name the node and use it later as reference. You can also use the `label` key on the node itself to place another node in relation to it (we can also use it to place a pic). Or do you want to place a something in place of the `Y`? I am confused …

Comment: No external graphic. I draw a steelyard with TikZ. I think, it should be something possible with `scope` at `node(Y){Y}` ....

Comment: On the other hand something like `node{\tikz[]{\draw circle(3mm)}}` seems to work. So if there's nothing better, I'll have to take that.

Comment: Nesting TikZ pictures should be your last resort, there's always the matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to use a drawing in place of a node is to use a (single-cell) matrix – which is a node that doesn't observe transformations.
This node still has a shape (by default, as always, a rectangle), inner and outer seps and also can be drawn and filled and …

And it can be used inside `forest`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  tight matrix/.style={matrix,
    every outer matrix/.append style={inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=auto}}}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em]
\node {A0}
  child { node {A1}
    child { node{X} }
    child { node[tight matrix]{\draw circle[radius=3mm];\\} }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{forest} for tree={l sep=3em, s sep=10em}
[A0 [A1 [X] [{\draw circle[radius=3mm];\\}, tight matrix]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image][image]